# SOMETIMES an java application windows opens in the foreground and SOMETIMES in the background

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, swt, rcp

I am working on Java desktop application for Windows which is able to opens multiple windows. I use Eclipse RCP. Opening a new windows of the app maybe triggered via REST call. To test the scenario of opening a new window via REST call I have a command application that sends a request. The command app is trigger via Windows Terminal.

Here starts the root problem: **Sometimes** a new window of Java app appears in front of the Windows Terminal and it is focused and **sometimes** in the background and not focused.

The expectation is that the new window will open in the foreground and focused.

I cannot get any concrete scenario for described behavior.

I tried to force set the new window to be active and focused programmatically in Java but there is no reactions on my commands.

The same behavior occurs when we send a REST call via web app.

Have you encountered this behavior?

Br

Comment: `jframe.setAlwaysOnTop(true);`

Comment: Possibly a Shell with `SWT.ON_TOP`as part of the style